# Custom PageIndicator from ViewPagerIndicator has no style

Tags: android, viewpagerindicator

I’m trying to put an indicator of new items (small badge showing that there is new content) in tabs, using `JakeWharton` / `Android-ViewPagerIndicator`.

I extended `PageIndicator` from library and created my custom `CustomPageIndicator`. Most of the things I copied from `TabPageIndicator`. I just changed the View that is returned in addTab method. This view is inflated from xml.

When I run my application the indicator created from `CustomPageIndicator` does not have any style set. All other indicator in app are just fine.

I tried to set style and background to both `ViewPagerIndicator` and  root view of my custom xml layout. The results were pretty bad. I got some coloring but highlighting didn't work etc.

Code for:

- [CustomPageIndicator](https://gist.github.com/pzagor2/4713748)
- [custom xml layout](https://gist.github.com/pzagor2/4713760)

How it looks like:

[image]

So what would i have to add to get the styling on my custom indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i got it to work with the help of this topic on github.
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/issues/94

Changes i made:

-Added a different super call to CustomTabView (this is view that i inflate form XML)

```
super(context, null,com.viewpagerindicator.R.attr.vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle);
```

-Changed the super call in CustomPageIndicator(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) constructor to

```
super(new ContextThemeWrapper(context,R.style.Theme_VPI), attrs);
```

R.style.Theme_VPI is a custom theme defined in my style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.VPI" parent="Theme.abstyle">
    <item name="vpiTabPageIndicatorStyle">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator</item>
</style>
```